# PHP and MySQL Cookie and Header doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have a problem and I hope someone will be able to find a solution.
I just changed hoster and the website doesn't work completely.
Basically the problem is that some code doesn't work.

Where it checks `if(!empty($db_password) and ($md5pass == $db_password))`

The echo works but the other things don't and it's not only there. I have a similar problem with other files as well.

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
if(isset($username))
{
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $md5pass = md5($password);

    $check_user = "SELECT ID,username,password FROM Members ";
    $check_user .= "WHERE username = '".$username."'";

    $checkuser_query = mysqli_query($dbconnection,$check_user);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkuser_query,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $db_userid = $row['ID'];
        $db_username = $row['username'];
        $db_password = $row['password'];
        $db_avatar = $row['avatar'];
    }

    if(!empty($db_password) and ($md5pass == $db_password))
    {
        echo 'you are not awesome.';
        setcookie("LoginAuthorised","LoginAuthorised",time()+7200,"/");
        setcookie("id",$db_userid,time()+7200,"/");
        setcookie("username",$db_username,time()+7200,"/");
        header("Location: user.php?value=confirm");
    }else
    {
        echo '<div id="error">Password does not match</div>';
    }       
}
    echo '<p></p><p></p>
         <div id="lg_login_form">
            <form name="login_form" method="post">
                <div id="lg_login_title">Log In</div>
                    <div id="lg_login_form2">
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user" id="username" value="" maxlength="20" />
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="20" />
                    <input name="submit_login" type="submit" value="Log In" id="lg_submit_log" />
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                    <div id="lg_control_text">You have to login to access User Panel</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        <form name="register_redirect" action="user.php?value=register" method="post"  id="lg_register_redirect" >
            <label>If you want to login you have to register first. Registering takes only a few moments and it gives you multiple features.<br/></label>
            <input name="submit_registration" type="submit" value="Register" id="lg_submit_reg_log" />
            <p></p>
        </form>
    </div>';
```

Comment: Is there any error message displayed on the page?

Comment: Try using `if(!empty($db_password) && ($md5pass == $db_password))` instead. `&&` has precedence over `AND` --- Plus you may want to use `ob_start();` for using header and cookies; it's been known to help. And you may want to put `header("Location: user.php?value=confirm");` above your cookies, in conjunction with using `ob_start();` which would need to be located over `session_start();`

Comment: This isn't enough information.  We don't know why that statement doesn't work.  You need to tell us what else you've figured out and where those variables are set.

Comment: Basically when I log in the cookies isn't set and the header doesn't work. In my registration I have an if and if it's true I should be redirected using header which doesn't work as well but the echo does.

Comment: The wired thing is that I tried with 2 other hosters and it worked but it doesn't work with this one. They gave me a temporary ftp until my domain is set, could that affect it ?

Comment: It could play a role, since the domain hasn't fully propagated . @user3161187

Comment: Nvm, I think it was a problem with the hoster because I changed it and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending headers before `setcookie()` is called, which is probably why you're having issues. Remove the line that says `echo 'you are not awesome.';`